# SwiftUI get Item for specific Id in Array/fetchedJson

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, xcode12

How to get the content from a fetched json file manually for a specific identifier?
For example: I want to display the text value for id 1, and later on replace the id with an variable to search for specific ids.

[
{
"id":1,
"text":"placeholder1"
},
{
"id":2,
"text":"placeholder2"
}
]

`@ObservedObject var fetch = FetchToDeviceInfo()`
`let txt = fetch[id: 1].text`
`Text("text for id 1: \(txt)")`

Edit: I found a way, but the performance is really bad.

```
 
@State private var array : [CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()
 ---------------------------------------------  
func getData(){

array.removeAll()
        
for d in fetch.deviceInfo {
            
            if d.id == 1 {
            
            var newArray : [CGFloat] = d.cpuTemp
            
            newArray.removeLast()
            
         array.append(contentsOf: newArray)
            } else {}
             
         }
 
         
    }
```

Comment: Look at the Apple SwiftUI Tutorials, specifically Handling User Input. The files within the provided sample project (Model and Resources folder) decode JSON strings and the tutorial goes over the basics on how to manipulate it and display it. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

Comment: thanks, but I have a kind of library and for each item in the library, I have more information in the json. So I need to select the json "Item" by passing the locally safed number in the "id sector" to get the specific data.

Comment: What is the content of `fetch’, what type is it?

Comment: it is the fetched json from my json api.